# Excel: Plot time series with only y values with positional x values (first y value is x=1, second y value is x=2, and so on) converted to time unit

Tags: excel, plot, timeserieschart, x-axis

In Excel I would like to plot a time series with only y values, which is possible with simply selecting the y values of a time series. In that case Excel matches the y value to a positional x value (see title of question).

The Question is: Is it possible to convert those positional x values to a time unit? In my case (see image) a data point is equivalent to 10 ms (more precise the distance from one point to the next). I want to display it in seconds, so that f.e. at x value 50 (times 10 ms) it would display 0,5 seconds. I tried to change the format of the number of the x axis but wasn't able to move the decimal point to the left.

Does anyone know the answer? Would appreciate any input. Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnRz.png